# Collision Detection Problems and Invalid Command Name?

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection, tkinter-canvas

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
drawpad = Canvas(root, width=600,height=600, background='white')
player = drawpad.create_rectangle(260,590,340,595, fill = "blue")
ball = drawpad.create_oval(293,576,307,590, fill = "white")
brick1 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,20,80,50, fill='green')
brick2 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,100,80,130, fill='green')
brick3 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,180,80,210, fill='green')
brick4 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,20,150,50, fill='green')
brick5 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,100,150,130, fill='green')
brick6 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,180,150,210, fill='green')
brick7 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,20,220,50, fill='green')
brick8 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,100,220,130, fill='green')
brick9 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,180,220,210, fill='green')
brick10= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,20,290,50, fill='green')
brick11= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,100,290,130, fill='green')
brick12= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,180,290,210, fill='green')
brick13= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,20,360,50, fill='green')
brick14= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,100,360,130, fill='green')
brick15= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,180,360,210, fill='green')
brick16= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,20,430,50, fill='green')
brick17= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,100,430,130, fill='green')
brick18= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,180,430,210, fill='green')
brick19= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,20,500,50, fill='green')
brick20= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,100,500,130, fill='green')
brick21= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,180,500,210, fill='green')
brick22= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,20,570,50, fill='green')
brick23= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,100,570,130, fill='green')
brick24= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,180,570,210, fill='green')
brickA1 = drawpad.create_rectangle(60,60,110,90, fill='cyan')
brickA2 = drawpad.create_rectangle(60,140,110,170, fill='cyan')
brickA3 = drawpad.create_rectangle(130,60,180,90, fill='cyan')
brickA4 = drawpad.create_rectangle(130,140,180,170, fill='cyan')
brickA5 = drawpad.create_rectangle(200,60,250,90, fill='cyan')
brickA6 = drawpad.create_rectangle(200,140,250,170, fill='cyan')
brickA7 = drawpad.create_rectangle(270,60,320,90, fill='cyan')
brickA8 = drawpad.create_rectangle(270,140,320,170, fill='cyan')
brickA9 = drawpad.create_rectangle(340,60,390,90, fill='cyan')
brickA10= drawpad.create_rectangle(340,140,390,170, fill='cyan')
brickA11= drawpad.create_rectangle(410,60,460,90, fill='cyan')
brickA12= drawpad.create_rectangle(410,140,460,170, fill='cyan')
brickA13= drawpad.create_rectangle(480,60,530,90, fill='cyan')
brickA14= drawpad.create_rectangle(480,140,530,170, fill='cyan')
bricklist = [brick1,brick2,brick3,brick4,brick5,brick6,brick7,brick8,brick9,brick10,brick11,brick12,brick13,brick14,brick15,brick16,brick17,brick18,brick19,brick20,brick21,brick22,brick23,brick24,brickA1,brickA2,brickA3,brickA4,brickA5,brickA6,brickA7,brickA8,brickA9,brickA10,brickA11,brickA12,brickA13,brickA14]
direction = 0
import random
randAngle = 0
angle = 0
overlap = 0
listPlace = 0
length = 0
brick = 0
class myApp(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global drawpad
        self.myParent = parent  
        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()
        # Score
        self.prompt = "Score:"

        self.label1 = Label(root, text=self.prompt, width=len(self.prompt), bg='green')
        self.label1.pack()

        self.score = 0

        self.scoreTxt = Label(root, text=str(self.score), width=3, bg='green')
        self.scoreTxt.pack()

        drawpad.pack()
        root.bind_all('<Key>', self.key)
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        global drawpad
        global ball
        global direction
        global angle
        global randAngle
        global listPlace
        global brick
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        px1,py1,px2,py2 = drawpad.coords(player)
        if y1 <= 0:
            direction = 5
        elif x1 >= px1 and x2 <= px2 and y2 >= py1:
            direction = -5
            randAngle = random.randint(0,12)
            angle = randAngle - 6
        elif x1 <= 0 and y2 <= 600 or x2 >= 600 and y2 <= 600:
            angle = -angle

        didWeHit = self.collisionDetect
        if didWeHit == True:
            #for x in bricklist:
            #   if x == brick: 
            brick = bricklist[listPlace]
            bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = drawpad.coords(brick)
            if x1 <= bx1 or x2 >= bx2:
                angle = -angle
            if y1 <= by1 or by2 >= y2:
                direction = -direction
            drawpad.delete(brick)

        drawpad.move(ball, angle, direction)
        drawpad.after(5,self.animate)


    def key(self,event):
        global drawpad
        global player
        global ball
        global direction
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        px1,py1,px2,py2 = drawpad.coords(player)
        if event.char == " ":
            direction = -5
        if event.char == "a":
            if x1 != 293 and y1 != 576 and x2 != 307 and y2 != 590 and px1 > 0:
                    drawpad.move(player,-8,0)
        if event.char == "d":
            if x1 != 293 and y1 != 576 and x2 != 307 and y2 != 590 and px2 < 600:
                    drawpad.move(player,8,0)

    def collisionDetect(self):
        global drawpad
        global bricklist
        global direction
        global angle
        global overlap
        global listPlace
        global length
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        overlap = drawpad.find_overlapping(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        length = len(overlap)
        if length > 1: 
            listPlace = overlap[1] - 3
            return True
            self.score = self.score + 5
            self.scoreTxt.config(text=str(self.score))



app = myApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

For a project in my computer class I am creating a brick breaker style game, and I'm just about done with writing it however the collision detection isn't working. There is a message when I run the program that says:

```
invalid command name "182718608Lcallit"
    while executing
"182718608Lcallit"
    ("after" script)
```

What does that mean and why isn't the collision detection functioning?

Okay edit:
I have another slightly different version of the same code, which I know the collision detection is working but only the score changes, the bricks don't disappear and the ball doesn't bounce. I don't understand why this following version has a working score while the first doesn't, and I don't understand why neither of the codes successfully delete the brick and bounce the ball. This code also has a similar error message, with just different numbers. Can someone please explain, I'm new to coding.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
drawpad = Canvas(root, width=600,height=600, background='white')
player = drawpad.create_rectangle(260,590,340,595, fill = "blue")
ball = drawpad.create_oval(293,576,307,590, fill = "white")
brick1 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,20,80,50, fill='green')
brick2 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,100,80,130, fill='green')
brick3 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,180,80,210, fill='green')
brick4 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,20,150,50, fill='green')
brick5 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,100,150,130, fill='green')
brick6 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,180,150,210, fill='green')
brick7 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,20,220,50, fill='green')
brick8 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,100,220,130, fill='green')
brick9 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,180,220,210, fill='green')
brick10= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,20,290,50, fill='green')
brick11= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,100,290,130, fill='green')
brick12= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,180,290,210, fill='green')
brick13= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,20,360,50, fill='green')
brick14= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,100,360,130, fill='green')
brick15= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,180,360,210, fill='green')
brick16= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,20,430,50, fill='green')
brick17= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,100,430,130, fill='green')
brick18= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,180,430,210, fill='green')
brick19= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,20,500,50, fill='green')
brick20= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,100,500,130, fill='green')
brick21= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,180,500,210, fill='green')
brick22= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,20,570,50, fill='green')
brick23= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,100,570,130, fill='green')
brick24= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,180,570,210, fill='green')
brickA1 = drawpad.create_rectangle(60,60,110,90, fill='cyan')
brickA2 = drawpad.create_rectangle(60,140,110,170, fill='cyan')
brickA3 = drawpad.create_rectangle(130,60,180,90, fill='cyan')
brickA4 = drawpad.create_rectangle(130,140,180,170, fill='cyan')
brickA5 = drawpad.create_rectangle(200,60,250,90, fill='cyan')
brickA6 = drawpad.create_rectangle(200,140,250,170, fill='cyan')
brickA7 = drawpad.create_rectangle(270,60,320,90, fill='cyan')
brickA8 = drawpad.create_rectangle(270,140,320,170, fill='cyan')
brickA9 = drawpad.create_rectangle(340,60,390,90, fill='cyan')
brickA10= drawpad.create_rectangle(340,140,390,170, fill='cyan')
brickA11= drawpad.create_rectangle(410,60,460,90, fill='cyan')
brickA12= drawpad.create_rectangle(410,140,460,170, fill='cyan')
brickA13= drawpad.create_rectangle(480,60,530,90, fill='cyan')
brickA14= drawpad.create_rectangle(480,140,530,170, fill='cyan')
bricklist = [brick1,brick2,brick3,brick4,brick5,brick6,brick7,brick8,brick9,brick10,brick11,brick12,brick13,brick14,brick15,brick16,brick17,brick18,brick19,brick20,brick21,brick22,brick23,brick24,brickA1,brickA2,brickA3,brickA4,brickA5,brickA6,brickA7,brickA8,brickA9,brickA10,brickA11,brickA12,brickA13,brickA14]
direction = 0
import random
randAngle = 0
angle = 0
overlap = 0
listPlace = 0
length = 0
brick = 0
class myApp(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global drawpad
        self.myParent = parent  
        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()
        # Score
        self.prompt = "Score:"

        self.label1 = Label(root, text=self.prompt, width=len(self.prompt), bg='green')
        self.label1.pack()

        self.score = 0

        self.scoreTxt = Label(root, text=str(self.score), width=3, bg='green')
        self.scoreTxt.pack()

        drawpad.pack()
        root.bind_all('<Key>', self.key)
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        global drawpad
        global ball
        global direction
        global angle
        global randAngle
        global listPlace
        global brick
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        px1,py1,px2,py2 = drawpad.coords(player)
        if y1 <= 0:
            direction = 5
        elif x1 >= px1 and x2 <= px2 and y2 >= py1:
            direction = -5
            randAngle = random.randint(0,12)
            angle = randAngle - 6
        elif x1 <= 0 and y2 <= 600 or x2 >= 600 and y2 <= 600:
            angle = -angle

        didWeHit = self.collisionDetect()
        if didWeHit == True:
            brick = bricklist[listPlace]
            bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = drawpad.coords(brick)
            if x1 <= bx1 or x2 >= bx2:
                angle = -angle
            if y1 <= by1 or by2 >= y2:
                direction = -direction

        drawpad.move(ball, angle, direction)
        drawpad.after(5,self.animate)


    def key(self,event):
        global drawpad
        global player
        global ball
        global direction
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        px1,py1,px2,py2 = drawpad.coords(player)
        if event.char == " ":
            direction = -5
        if event.char == "a":
            if x1 != 293 and y1 != 576 and x2 != 307 and y2 != 590 and px1 > 0:
                    drawpad.move(player,-8,0)
        if event.char == "d":
            if x1 != 293 and y1 != 576 and x2 != 307 and y2 != 590 and px2 < 600:
                    drawpad.move(player,8,0)

    def collisionDetect(self):
        global drawpad
        global bricklist
        global direction
        global angle
        global overlap
        global listPlace
        global length
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        overlap = drawpad.find_overlapping(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        length = len(overlap)
        if length > 1: 
            listPlace = overlap[1] - 3
            brick = bricklist[listPlace]
            bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = drawpad.coords(brick)
            if x1 <= bx1 or x2 >= bx2:
                angle = -angle
            if y1 <= by1 or by2 >= y2:
                direction = -direction
            self.score = self.score + 5
            self.scoreTxt.config(text=str(self.score))   
            return True
            drawpad.delete(brick)


app = myApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your collisionDetect method deletes a brick, but then you try to do things with the brick later (in the `if didWeHit` part of your code). Make sure that you wait to delete the brick until you've done everything you need to with it!

In Tkinter, this kind of error occurs if you try to do something with an object that has been deleted. Tkinter assigns a number to each Tk object that it creates, which is the funny number in your error that you got. It is trying to execute the command that it named `182718608Lcallit`, but that doesn't exist any more since you deleted the corresponding brick.